# What is the first major film that used drones?

Tags: production, film-industry, cinematography

I assume with the switch to digital film-making and light weight 4K or higher resolution cameras, shots that previously would have required a helicopter are now being done with drones at much lower cost.

If so, what was the first major film to make extensive use of drones (multiple shots, perhaps a minute or two of finished film, not just a few seconds), e.g. an example would be opening scenes of any James Bond film which traditionally would have been done with a helicopter.

Comment: @DForck42 good question, updated my question with an example.

Comment: I can't make a more detailed research right now for the first major film, but i found this list https://skytango.com/drones-in-movies-7-hollywood-movies-filmed-with-drones/, I can add as an answer if you would like =)

Comment: @GustavoGabriel Yes, please add this as an answer, listing the seven films.  When I updated my question to use James Bond openings as examples, I was thinking of Skyfall but had no idea they had actually used drones already five years ago.

Comment: @DForck42 Hmm, I felt the question could rather be opened towards a more thorough historical analysis about the use of drones in film-making, rather than narrowing it down to a mere "who was first?" thing (or a list of films, for that matter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the **first** major film who used drones to film scenes that in other films were done with helicopters.

But I found this [list](https://skytango.com/drones-in-movies-7-hollywood-movies-filmed-with-drones/) which has 7 **major** movies that used drones, and a couple of those are James Bond movies which you quoted in your question.

- Skyfall (2012)

> Sam Mendes’ Skyfall, starring Daniel Craig, Javier Bardem, and Naomie Harris, was the first of the James Bond movies to use drones for filming aerial footage.

- The Expendables 3 (2014)

> The opening scene was shot using drones. With a moving train, a low-flying helicopter dropping and collecting people from the train, bullets flying, explosions and soldier action, it was not an easy scene to capture on camera.

- The Wolf of Wall Street (2013)

> Martin Scorsese’s film The Wolf of Wall Street used the US-based drone cinematography company Freefly Cinema to capture the aerial shots of the pool party.

- Chappie (2015)

> In Chappie, the latest movie by South African director Neill Blomkamp after the critically acclaimed District 9, drones have been used intensively.
>   The camera on the drone was used as the POV (Point of View) of one of the robot characters.

- Spectre (2015)

> Sam Mendes’s Spectre, James Bond‘s latest movie, makes ample use of drone shots.
>   Helicopter Film Services (HFS), a UK-based helicopter and drone aerial filming company founded by Jeremy Braben, was the company chosen to provide drone aerial footage.

- Jurassic World (2015)

> Team 5 Aerial System Rentals are another experienced California-based aerial company who have embraced drones as a way to get unique aerial shots from a lower perspective than a helicopter.

- Captain America: Civil War (2016)

> Due for release in 2016, Captain America: Civil War features drone footage from Pictorvision and aerial filming from Helicopter Film Services (HFS).

More details can be found [HERE](https://skytango.com/drones-in-movies-7-hollywood-movies-filmed-with-drones/).

Another movies scenes filmed with drones [HERE](http://dronelife.com/2014/09/25/movies-scenes-shot-with-drones/).